# What kinds of electric motors can produce a lot of power at low RPM?

Tags: motors

Are there electric motors that can produce a lot of power at low RPM? Why couldn't a motor produce as much power as needed if you give it enough voltage? Why would an electric motor be able to produce more power at a higher RPM?

Comment: Power is equal to force times distance, or in the case of motors (rpms * torque). As the rpms goes to 0 so does the power output. If you try to turn a crank, and the crank doesn't budge, then you're imparting no energy to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Motors that produce lots of power at low RPM are big and heavy. The optimum solution is to instead use a small, high-speed motor connected to a reduction gearset- which is called a *gearmotor*.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the motor is not really important if it is adequate for the power in, and the power out. Think of the motor not as producing power, but transferring it. Depending on the capacity of transfer that you need (Wattage), you can determine the correct size for your motor. Once you know that the motor is adequate, You simply need to modify your gear ratios so that you receive the amount of torque desired for the application. If the motor is spinning at 1000rpm, and you reduce that to 500 rpm with a 2:1. you have increased your torque by double and so on. To illustrate: a motor and generator can be the same thing if you reverse the direction the power input, So if you use a large slow torque, and increase the speed, you have the opposite effect and you can generate large amounts of voltage.